# check if item exists in json file then get it if exists. And if not complete executing the code

Tags: javascript, json

I get a json file from outer link by ajax call. i want to check element is exists in this json file or not and get it if exists. because it changes every time and items increases or decreases. If I get item and this item not existing, I get error and the code not complete. i want to check this item json.children[1].children and json.children[2].children ,..... if exists.

```
{
    "num": 1,
    "name": "aa",
    "properites": [
        {
            "name": "prop1",
            "value": "value1"
        }
    ],
    "children": [
       
        {
            "num2": 1,
            "name2": "name2",
            "properites": [
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "value": "value"
                }
            ],
            "children": []
        },
       
        {
            "name": 1,
            "num": "1",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "value": "value"
                }
            ],
            "children": []
        .......................... big json file
```

I have tried to get these Items and set in local storage to use in table by this:

```
localStorage.setItem("row1-item1", json.children[1].children);
    localStorage.setItem("row1-item2", json.children[2].children);
    localStorage.setItem("row1-item3", json.children[3].children);
    localStorage.setItem("row1-item4", json.children[4].children);
    localStorage.setItem("row2-item1", json.name[1].children);
    localStorage.setItem("row2-item2", json.name[2].children);
    localStorage.setItem("row2-item3", json.name[3].children);
    localStorage.setItem("row2-item4", json.name[4].children);
```

the problem here is if json.children[4].children not existing the code not complete the next line and jump out of ajax call even if json.name[1].children is exists. I tried try/catch but not solved it

Comment: I think you just need to get the json in a variable and use if and else statements to check for present and absent values

Comment: I used it if an item existing get it. But the code also stop execution and get out of the ajax call and complete the other codes

Comment: How to get it in a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `map`

```
json.children.map((children,index)=>{
    localStorage.setItem('row${index}-item${index}`, children);
}
```

Or you can use `forEach` or `for loop` instead of `map`.

Comment: I used them but it stop looping from the item that not existing

Comment: I used also try catch but the execution stop if item is not existing

Comment: what you want to do please mansion properly.

Comment: Getting items from json files. These item may be more or less than current. So, i want to check if existing before getting them. If i get item from ajax call the ajax will be aborted if the item not existing